# Running Gradle task with environment variables

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle

I have the following Gradle task:

```
task runCli(type: JavaExec) {
    group = "Execution"
    description = "Run the CLI tool"
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = "commandline.CommandLineToolKt"
}
```

Then, in the project root folder, I run:

```
export MONGODB_HOST=localhost && ./gradlew runCli
```

In my code, I have:

```
System.getenv("MONGODB_HOST")
```

When I run the app, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: System.getenv("MONGODB_HOST") must not be null
```

Comment: can you try `MONGODB_HOST=localhost  ./gradlew runCli` or `MONGODB_HOST=localhost  gradle runCli`?

Comment: the first just changes folder to `gradle`. the second says `gradle command not found`